# Does a measurable mapping have to be one-to-one and onto?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

According to the definition by Prof. Folland (p.43~p.44):

> A mapping $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is called $(M,N)$-measurable, (or just measurable when $M$ and $N$ are understood, if $f^{-1}(E)\in M$ for all $E\in N$.  $M,N$ are $\sigma$-algebra.

I am really confused that does the map $f$ have to be one-to-one and onto according to this definition?

Since we define the inverse map, if it is not one-to-one and onto, then how to define its inverse map?

Or could anyone please support an example to disagree this?

Comment: You are not using the inverse map. The notation $f^{-1}(E)$ stands for pre-image, that is 
$$
f^{-1}(E):=\{ x \in X : f(x) \in E\}
$$
That said, you can find maps that are not one to one nor onto that are measurable. For example in the usual setting $f:\Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$, any constant map is measurable.

Comment: @AlonsoDelfín So in your case, $f$ is not a measurable "function", just a measurable "map"?  I think if it is a measurable "function", should be one-to-one and onto, the definition for a "function". I am not sure if I am making sense.

Comment: You don't need the inverse function to compute the pre.image $f^{-1}(E)$. Here $f^{-1}(E)$ is a subset of $X$ for any $E$ subset of $Y$. E.G, say $f:\Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ is given by $f(x)=1$ for all $x \in \Bbb{R}$. Clearly $f$ is not onto $\Bbb{R}$ and also $f$ is not one to one. Now, for any open set $U \subset \Bbb{R}$, we have 
$$
f^{-1}(U)= \begin{cases} \Bbb{R} & if \ 1 \in U \\  \emptyset & if \ 1 \notin U\end{cases}
$$
Therefore $f^{-1}(U)$ is measurable for any open set $U \subset \Bbb{R}$. This gives that $f$ is a measurable function if we give $\Bbb{R}$ the Borel sigma algebra

Comment: I am using map and function indistinctly to refer to the same concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f$ is a function from $X$ to $Y$.  We can use $f$ to define a **new** fucntion $\phi$ from $\mathcal P(Y)$ to $\mathcal P(X)$.  Here, $\mathcal P(X)$ means the **power set** of $X$, the set of all subsets of $X$.  The new function $\phi$ is defined by
$$
\phi(T) = \{x \in X\;:\; f(x) \in T\},\qquad\text{for all } T \in \mathcal P(Y)
$$

Now the confusing part.  Conventionally, we write $\phi = f^{-1}$.  Even though $f$ may not have an inverse function.  And if $f$ does have an inverse function, we end up with the notation $f^{-1}$ for two different things.  Only slightly different, to be sure, but different.  One maps $\mathcal P(Y)$ to $\mathcal P(X)$, the other maps $Y$ to $X$.